# Intellij: Exception condition statement crashes on unreachable line

Tags: java, debugging, exception, intellij-idea

I want my java program to only break when the exception stack contains a certain string. However, when I specify a more complex break condition, I get an illogical error.

I suspect that `this` behaves differently than in normal java code. I tried to store it in a temporary variable, but that gave errors too.
`Object self = this;`

This is the error message Intellij gives when an exception is thrown:

```
Problem processing VM event:
Breakpoint: 'Any exception'
Error: Failed to evaluate breakpoint condition

if(this instanceof java.lang.Exception){
    System.out.println("Got here"); // Never gets printed
    return ((java.lang.Exception)this).getStackTrace().toString().contains("TypesTest$$");
}
return false;

Reason: Inconvertible types; cannot cast 'java.lang.Class<T>' to 'java.lang.Exception'
Would you like to stop at the breakpoint?
```

`this` should be castable to `Exception`, because it is checked for that first. Any idea why this happens, or how I could solve this?

Comment: Because your class never be Exception class, until unless it extends Exception class

Comment: But if my class isn't an Exception class, the line with the cast should never be triggered, no?